# How do I move a sphere towards, starting from players position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a game in **Unity**. My task is to when player presses the "1' key, it shoots out a sphere to the player.transform.forward position, until it collides with an enemy.

The problem is, when the sphere has been shot, while its flying, I can controll its moving X value by turning the player right or left. So the sphere moves with me, but it should not. This is of course because in **Update()**, I move it in the player's facing direction. How can I make the sphere start facing at the players direction, but after move independently?

This is the code that moves the sphere

```
private float speed = 4.0f;

void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(player.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
```

Comment: dont use the players position for the move, use its own

Comment: I need to start moving the sphere where the player is facing at that moment

Comment: So instantiate it facing that direction and move it

Comment: please post the code where you instantiate/initialize the sphere

Comment: This has already been solved, but thank you guys for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save it's inital "forward" direction and reference it afterwards

```
public GameObject player;

private float speed = 4.0f;
private Vector3 direction;

private void Awake() //I used Awake() as example asuming you are instantiating the sphere, 
{                    //but you could set the value of the direction when you press "1" too

    direction = player.transform.forward;
}

void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(direction * Time.deltaTime * speed);
}
```

Comment: This is one option but requries to A) set the player reference and B) note that `Translate` by default works in **local** space. So if you want to pass in the direction as world space vector you nee `transform.Translate(..., Space.World);`!

Comment: That is! I Instantiate this prefab in the player file, and then in the sphere's file Start() method i do set this direction. Perfect! Many thanks, have a nice day guys.

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate it with the correct orientation

```
Instantiate(rangedAttack, spawnPosition, player.transform.rotation);
```

Now its own forward vector points the same direction as the one of the player.

And then simply do

```
private float speed = 4.0f;

void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
}
```

**Note** [`Translate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) by default works in the [`Space.Self`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Space.Self.html) so the local space of this transform. You do not want to pass in a worldspace Vector here but rather move only in the local `Z` axis!

If you pass in a worldspace vector you will nee to pass **`Space.World`**

```
transform.Translate(vector, Space.World);
```